# Agrupar datos con array

Tags: php, array

tengo el siguiente array:

```
 0 => string '1320-GIOVANN'

 1 => string '17123-GIOVANN'

 2 => string '31234-ALBERT'

 3 => string '30615-ALBERT'
```

Lo que deseo es que los datos queden agrupados o "unidos" por el nombre de la persona, algo así:

```
 0 => string '1320-17123-GIOVANN'

 1=> string '31234-30615-ALBERT'
```

Código actual:

```
foreach ($datos as $valor) { 
  $valor1 = explode("-", $valor); 
  $consecutivo=$valor1[0]; 
  $nombre=$valor1[1]; 
  array_push($arreglop,$usuario);
  if((in_array($usuario,$arreglop)){ 
    $arreglop=array(); array_push($arreglop,$consecutivo); 
  } else{  
   $arreglop2=array(); array_push($arreglop2,$consecutivo,$usuario); 
  } 
}
```

Cómo puedo lograrlo? Gracias.

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: foreach ($datos as $valor) {
$valor1 = explode("-", $valor);
$consecutivo=$valor1[0];
$nombre=$valor1[1];

array_push($arreglop,$usuario); 
if((in_array($usuario,$arreglop)){
$arreglop=array();
array_push($arreglop,$consecutivo); 
}
else{
$arreglop2=array();
 array_push($arreglop2,$consecutivo,$usuario); 
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Algunos consejos:**

Tu código:

```
foreach ($datos as $valor) { 
  $valor1 = explode("-", $valor); 
  $consecutivo=$valor1[0]; 
  $nombre=$valor1[1]; 
  array_push($arreglop,$usuario);
  if((in_array($usuario,$arreglop)){ 
    $arreglop=array();
    array_push($arreglop,$consecutivo); 
  } else{  
   $arreglop2=array();
   array_push($arreglop2,$consecutivo,$usuario); 
  } 
}
```

Uno de los errores que se ve a simple vista es el `array_push($arreglop,$usuario);` ya que no compruebas antes si existe el usuario ya.
Otro que se ve a simple vista son los `$arreglop=array();` y `$arreglop2=array();` dentro del propio `foreach` ya que cada vez que hace el `foreach` vacía todo el array ya contenido. Para solucionarlo tienes que ponerlos fuera del `foreach`.

**Solución:**

```
<?php
$datos=array();
array_push($datos,"1320-GIOVANN");
array_push($datos,"17123-GIOVANN");
array_push($datos,"31234-ALBERT");
array_push($datos,"30615-ALBERT");
$arreglop=array();
$arreglop2=array();
foreach ($datos as $valor) { 
    $valor1 = explode("-", $valor); 
    $consecutivo=$valor1[0]; 
    $usuario=$valor1[1]; 
    if(!(in_array($usuario,$arreglop))){
        array_push($arreglop,$usuario);
    }
    if(!(array_key_exists($usuario,$arreglop2))){
        $arreglop2[$usuario] = $consecutivo."-".$usuario;
    }
    else{
        $temp=explode("-",$arreglop2[$usuario]);
        array_splice($temp,-1);
        array_push($temp,$consecutivo);
        array_push($temp,$usuario);
        $arreglop2[$usuario]=implode("-",$temp);
    }
}
print_r($arreglop);
echo "<br>";
print_r($arreglop2);
?>
```

El `$arreglop` devolverá los nombres que se ejecutan y el `$arreglop2` devolverá mediante las claves del usuario de esta manera: `...xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx-nombre`.
Para ordenar el `$arreglop2` lo he convertido en un array mediante `explode`, luego he eliminado el último valor con el `array_splice` (que siempre es el nombre) y le he añadido el nuevo valor y el nombre con el `array_push` y por último he vuelto a transformar en un string con `implode`

Comment: Gracias! Era justo lo que buscaba!